# Update bash in shell scripts on macos

Tags: bash

Hi I'm trying to update bash in my shell scripts to v5 on macos. Example shell scripts:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
which bash
echo $BASH_VERSION
```

Updating bash in my terminal is successfull however in any of my existing shell scripts, it keeps on falling back to v3.2.57(1)-release (/bin/bash) wile i want to use v5.x (which is in /usr/local/bin/bash). Whenever I change the PATH variable so that /bin/ is not included (only /bin/env) I get a different error:

```
env: bash: No such file or directory
```

Whenever I do include it, v3.2 is used in the script..

Things I did:

- Removed /bin/bash from /etc/shells
- Tried change PATH variable so that #!/usr/bin/env bash still works but v3.2 is not used
- Add /usr/local/bin to path which results in`./my-script: line 215: sh: command not found`

Anyone has any more tips I can try?

My Path configuration:

```
#start path from fresh
export PATH=/usr/local/bin
export PATH=$PATH:/bin
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin/
echo $PATH #output = /usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin/
```

Comment: Don't add `env` or 'bash' to PATH -- they are commands, not paths. Don't exclude `/bin` from PATH. Add `/usr/local/bin` to the front end of PATH, so it gets called first.

Comment: @benwiggy Thanks, I've changed the config but I still have the same error. Wil update my begin post

Comment: If you do `which bash` on the Terminal prompt, what do you get?

Comment: /usr/local/bin/bash. And when I execute the version it's the one I want.
/usr/local/bin/bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.2.12(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin21.6.0)

Comment: So what is the problem, then?

Comment: That when I run a shell script and print the bash version used in that script it still points to 3.2.57(1)-release. Even though when I print which bash in that script '/usr/local/bin/bash' is returned

Comment: Which bash version are you using as the shell to call the script from?

Comment: 'bash --version ' in the shell returns 'GNU bash, version 5.2.12(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin21.6.0)'

Comment: The only way to reproduce this here is to run `PATH=/bin ./your-script`. What do you get when you run `PATH=/usr/local/bin ./your-script` (all in one line)?

Comment: With `your-script` being the sample script from the top of your question. Please add a line `echo $PATH` as well, and run it both directly, and with the version from my previous comment. Then copy/paste both results in the question.

Comment: @nohillside, % PATH=/usr/local/bin ./your-script.sh -r returns ./your-script.sh: line 7: dirname: command not found ./your-script.sh: line 9: git: command not found So it doesn't want to run the script because it cannot find the dirname nor git command. When I run ./your-script.sh -r (included printing the path in the script) /usr/local/bin/bash 3.2.57(1)-release is returned

Comment: Please create a script which only includes the three lines you list at the top of your post, and add a `echo $PATH` as a forth line; and then run it with both the ways I described. Afterwards add the result to the question with an edit, too much gets lost in comments.

Comment: @nohillside, I just found out it is caused by running script B in script A via the shell script. When I print the version in script A it's v5, the prints in B are v3. Forgot to mention in all my previous posts that all my logging happened in script b... sorry about that (I'll update the beginpost with this info..).

Comment: Thanks for helping me debug this issues @noh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After correcting my path config as was suggested in the comments. I found out the bash version in the script was actually set correctly in the original script but not in the script that followed after that. So the problem was script A was calling script B by doing

```
sh next-script-to-run.sh params #runs in v3
```

After changing this to run the script without the sh command. All scripts ran in bash v5:

```
./next-script-to-run.sh params #runs in v5
```